# Text quality in processing

Tags: java, fonts, processing

Why does the text quality in [Processing](http://processing.org/) not look as good as Flash? In general it looks slightly grainy, and hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem as well. I found that if you continually overwrite the text (in the `draw` loop for example) without 'wiping' the underlying surface (by calling `background` in the `draw` loop for example) the text becomes jagged.

I think this is because the semi-transparent corners on the letters due to antialiasing get written over and over until they become fully opaque.

Take a look at this example, (you will have to create a font 'ArialMT-20')

```
PFont fontA;

void setup() {
  size(300, 100);
  fill(0);
  fontA = loadFont("ArialMT-20.vlw");
  textFont(fontA, 20);
  // Background drawn once here
  background(255);
}

void draw() {
  // When mouse is held down, the background is wiped
  if (mousePressed) {
    background(255);
  }
  text("Hi there", 20, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put the smooth() command inside the setup() method and be sure you are loading a font that exist in your system or inside your data folder.

IMHO the font rendering quality in processing is quite good :)